# Cannot access Help from Start or F1 on an old Dell Inspiron 2500

Tags: laptop

Am helping a friend with her Dell Inspiron 2500 Laptop, but cant access the Help and Support program from either the start menu or from pressing any F keys.
I know the logical option for this dinosaur but spending more than a dollar on this thing is not in her cards(nor mine).  Any suggestions.  I've removed all the old, unnecessary programs abut have yet to reboot XP.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you uninstalled this program from the Dell web site for your computer model:

[Dell Help and Support Customizations](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R33567&SystemID=INS_PNT_CEL_P3CG_2500&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=1546&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=25&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=37013)